# iOS : Inverse Cosine

Tags: ios, swift, math, trigonometry

I am trying to write an algorithm in Swift to work out the angles of a triangle.  For ref check https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sss-triangles.html

I am trying to fine the cos−1 command which I believe is inverse cosine

I have tried **acos** and **acosh**, both do not produce the correct value based on this site http://www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/Arccos_Calculator.htm

Does anyone know what the cos-1 function is on iOS

```
//https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sss-triangles.html
totalDistance = 8
arm1 = 6
arm2 = 7

var angleA = (pow(arm1, 2) +  pow(arm2, 2) - pow(totalDistance,2)) / (2 *  arm1 * arm2)
print(angleA) // I get 0.25 : correct
print( acos(angleA)) // I get 1.31811607165282 : should be 75.5
print( acosh(angleA)) // I get nan
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The inverse is `acos` for arccos. The result is in radians, you have to translate into degrees to get to your wanted result.

```
print( acos(angleA)*180/Pi)
```

If you scroll down in the arccos calculator, you will also find the radians value represented.

Comment: Thank you, why is everything always in radian (All the OpenGL Stuff I done is to)

Comment: Because mathematics uses radians. Degrees are an entirely arbitrary unit (there are other - grads, for example, 100 in a right angle, very metric), but radians are not arbitrary - the length of arc on a unit circle subtended by one radian == 1 exactly, since the perimeter of the full circle = 2π. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian